# How to grab certain word inside contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

### EDIT: textarea -> contenteditable div

I am trying to make a script tool which grabs a certain word from contenteditable div and then changes it into another word.

To show you more clearly of what I'm aiming for, the tool should 'look like' the snippet below(although script is not ready): by clicking the button, `this is a sample text, this is another text` should be replaced to `that is a sample text, that is another text`. All two `this`s switches to `that`s.

```html
<div contenteditable="true">this is a sample text, this is another text</div><br>
<button>change 'this' to 'that'</button>
```

So I've faced my first problem; what is a way to grab all 'certain word' inside the entire text in a contenteditable div? Jquery solutions may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added here an id for your button and your textarea.

To achieve this you can add an eventlistener to your button element and let it listen to the click event.

When the button gets pressed get the text of the div with the textContent property and reassing it with the textContent property but replace all occurences of *old word* with *new word* by using the *replaceAll()* method.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', replacer);

function replacer(){
let tx = document.getElementById('txarea');
tx.textContent = tx.textContent.replaceAll('this', 'that');
}
```

```html
<div id="txarea">this is a sample text, this is another text</div><br>
<button id="btn">change 'this' to 'that'</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question a little bit: what I actually want is contenteditable div instead of textarea, sorry for the confusion. Would it work similarly?

Comment: Please use `value` instead of `textContent` for input and textarea elements. You click the button -> add another "this" inside the textarea -> click the button again -> will not change *this* to *that*

Comment: For div it works the same I have updated the textarea to a div.

Comment: @adiga true ty for the advice

Comment: @adiga `value` will not work with `div`, use `text` instead :)

Comment: @MaiPhuong OP's code originally had `textarea`. divs obviously don't have a value

Answer (score 1):

With current JS there is no need for jquery most of the time. This standart JS snippet should do the trick:

```js
const editableText = document.getElementById('editable-text')
function changeWord() {
  const value = editableText.textContent
  editableText.textContent = value.replaceAll('this', 'that')
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="editable-text">this is a sample text, this is another text</div><br>
<button onclick="changeWord()">change 'this' to 'that'</button>
```

Comment: **EDIT: textarea -> contenteditable div** --> So use `textContent ` instead of `value`

Comment: @MaiPhuong Changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const x = document.getElementById('changetext');
function changeText() {
  const changeValue = x.textContent;
  x.textContent = changeValue.replaceAll('this','that');
};
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
<textarea id="changetext" style="width:100%;">this is a sample text, this is another text</textarea><br>
<input type="button" onclick="changeText()" value="change 'this' to 'that'"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` version looks more elegant & concise.

```js
$("#btn").on("click", () => {
  const $txarea = $("#txarea");
  var text = $txarea.text();
  $txarea.text(text.replaceAll('this', 'that'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txarea">this is a sample text, this is another text</div><br>
<button id="btn">change 'this' to 'that'</button>
```